# Blazor: Browser doen't update style attribute of HTML button

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, blazor

I am using Blazor. I have a grid of buttons in a component and am dynamically setting their individual background-image and border-style attributes with variables returned by methods as users perform certain clicks in other components.

```
@for (int id = 0; id < 24; id++)
{
     var buttonId = id;
     <button style="background-image: url(@GetImageFilePath(id)); border-style: @GetBorderStyle(id)"
                                @onclick="@(e => PlayerGridClick(e, buttonId))"></button>
}
```

Both methods in the above code return strings and so the code dynamically updates when NotifyStateChanged() action is invoked by the service that provides the data for the component.

If I view the source code in the browser I confirm that both attributes change just as I require, however, only the image attribute is rendered by the browser. If I refresh the browser the border-style attribute is then actioned.

I have tried Chrome and Firefox and both act the same.

Anyone out there have any clues?

Thanks

Further info requested:

The data service implements NotifyStateChanged like this:

```
public event Action OnChange;
private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
```

The client components subscribe like this:

```
// Subscribe to the state of change notification for the TurnSerice
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    turnService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
}

// Remove subscription to avoid memory leak
public void Dispose()
{
    turnService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
}
```

The client retrieves the data like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    player = await turnService.GetPlayerAsync(nPlayer);
    // if player has piece in hand:
    if(player.pieceInHand.pieceType!=ePieceType.none)
    {
        // calculate where they can place the piece without it being flipped
        // which column?
        int column = player.nPlotSource % 6;
        // highlight all square in this column
        bButtonBorderOn[column] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[column+6] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[column+12] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[column+18] = true;
        // which row?
        int row = player.nPlotSource / 6;
        // highlight all square in this row
        bButtonBorderOn[row * 6] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[row * 6+1] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[row * 6+2] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[row * 6+3] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[row * 6+4] = true;
        bButtonBorderOn[row * 6+5] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            bButtonBorderOn[i] = false;
    }
    //turnService.Test();

}
```

The setting of the bButtonBorderOn is rather crude but it is just to get it working. Finally the variable is set during the rendering of the component like this:

```
protected string GetBorderStyle(int id)
{
     if (bButtonBorderOn[id])
         return "solid";

     return "none";
}
```

Thanks again :)

Comment: Perhaps it is related to NotifyStateChanged() ...Could you please show all your related code.

Comment: maybe it's a caching problem try hard refresh with shift+ctrl+R

Comment: Added the other code as requested. I don't think it's a caching problem but I tried shift+ctrl+R anyway - it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

The purpose of the dynamic styling was to highlight to a player of the game where they could potentially place a token and get bonus points. So despite the highlighting not working, I moved on to implement the placement rules and found that the data had not initialised properly - extra points were not being awarded.

To solve the placement rule problem I moved the data variable for the styling to the data source class. In doing this the styling problem was also solved.

I am still a beginner to Blazor. Lesson learned: Components are not reliable keepers of data :)

Thanks to all those who took the time to read my question.